# Контрол для отображение текста с картинками в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Мне нужно в программе выводить информацию в виде текста с картинками. Пробовал использовать стандартный **RichTextBox**, но это не очень хороший вариант. Во-первых, он хранит картинки в несжатом виде и если у меня много картинок, то и памяти он жрет много. Во-вторых, вставлять картинки не так уж и просто, и иногда есть проблемы с отображением. Какой еще есть вариант для отображение такой информации в **Windows Forms** (или в **Windows Presentation Foundation**)?

Comment: Информацию нужно только выводить? Или редактировать тоже?

Comment: при загрузке картинки вы можете на ее основе создать другую сжатую/уменьшенную и вставить в RichTextBox.

Comment: как вариант можно использовать так же `WebControl`, получите все прелести html

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Только выводить

Comment: @Dmitry Что за WebControl? А то в стандартных контролах я его не нашел

Comment: @AndriyGoliyad извиняюсь, конечно же WebBrowser

Comment: _"(или в Windows Presentation Foundation)?"_ -- для WPF пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487737/196972)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> хранит картинки в несжатом виде и если у меня много картинок ...

Можно изменить размер и другие параметры у картинок. Во время загрузки создаете новый Bitmap и в него выводите загруженное изображение. В WinForms примерно так:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static Image LoadImage(string path, int width, int height) {
    var img = Image.FromFile(path);
    var res = new Bitmap(width, height);
    res.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(res)) {
        var dst = new Rectangle(0, 0, res.Width, res.Height);
        g.DrawImage(img, dst);
    }
    return res;
}

var f = new Form();
new PictureBox() { 
  Parent = f, 
  Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
  Image = LoadImage(@"C:\Temp\Pic.png", 50, 50) };
f.ShowDialog();
```