# Изображение в ListBoxItem WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Имеется шаблон для ListBoxItem, который содержит элементы Image и Label. Как при создании элемента ListBoxItem(с использованием шаблона) через код C# можно загрузить картинку в Image?

Comment: Вы не должны создавать `ListBoxItem` вручную. Просто укажите в шаблоне привязку к DataContext'у

Comment: @VladD а как в этом случае обратиться к image?

Comment: Ну, вы пишете что-то наподобие `<Image Source="{Binding Img}"/>`, и устанавливаете `Img` в вашем DataContext'е, отвечающем за элемент списка.

Comment: Если ответ решает ваш вопрос, вам стоит его принять (зелёная галка сбоку).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Width="300" Height="300">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image MaxWidth="50" MaxHeight="50" Source="{Binding Img}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lbl}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
  public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public Window1() {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = new ObservableCollection<object>() {
          new { Img=new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Temp\i1.jpg")), Lbl="i1" },
          new { Img=new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Temp\i2.jpg")), Lbl="i2" } };
    }
  }
}
```